# Shell script with Sum of odd numers from command line

Tags: linux, shell

i really tried to make this program to work but it gives me all times errors...
I want to run it like ./sum.sh 1 2 4 5 10
The output must be something like that The sum of odd numers is 16

There is what I did until now:

```
 #! /bin/bash

suma=0
for arg in $*
do
   if [ `expr $arg % 2 ` -eq 0 ] 
    then
       suma= ` expr $suma + $arg `
   fi
done

echo "Sum of odd numers is : $suma "
```

Comment: are you counting `10` as odd number as well? Else how the sum of odd numbers in 16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space after = in this line:

```
   suma= ` expr $suma + $arg `
```

Like this:

```
   suma=` expr $suma + $arg `
```

And your script will be correct.

```
./o.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
Sum of odd numers is : 12
```